# What is the hyperscan::Regex equivalent of regex::Regex::replace?

Tags: regex, rust

I'm rewriting this code:

```
use regex::Regex;
use std::fs;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let contents = fs::read_to_string("/home/jerzy/trackers_best.txt")
        .expect("Something went wrong reading the file");
    println!("Give me the magnet link.");

    let mut magnet = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut magnet)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    magnet = magnet.trim().to_string();

    let re = Regex::new(r"\&tr=.{3,1000}").expect("Failed to initialize the variable `re`.");

    magnet = re.replace(&magnet, contents).to_string();

    println!("The updated magnet link:\n{}", magnet);
}
```

`/home/jerzy/trackers_best.txt` is a text file that gets automatically downloaded every evening to my home directory from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ngosang/trackerslist/master/trackers_best.txt with the help of `wget` and `cron`.

I want to use the [hyperscan](https://crates.io/crates/hyperscan) crate instead of the [regex](https://crates.io/crates/regex) crate to improve the performance.

The new code:

```
use hyperscan::regex::Regex;
use std::fs;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let contents = fs::read_to_string("/home/jerzy/trackers_best.txt")
        .expect("Something went wrong reading the file");
    println!("Give me the magnet link.");

    let mut magnet = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut magnet)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    magnet = magnet.trim().to_string();

    let re = Regex::new(r"\&tr=.{3,1000}").expect("Failed to initialize the variable `re`.");

    magnet = re.replace(&magnet, contents).to_string();

    println!("The updated magnet link:\n{}", magnet);
}
```

The dependencies section of my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
hyperscan = "0.2.2"
```

This code does not compile, I get the following output from the compiler:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `replace` found for struct `Regex` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:26:14
   |
26 |  magnet = re.replace(&magnet, contents).to_string();
   |              ^^^^^^^ method not found in `Regex`
```

How might I rewrite the line in question? What method should I use instead of `.replace()`?

I looked for resources about using `hyperscan`, but there is not much on [their GitHub](https://github.com/flier/rust-hyperscan).